# List the contents of a directory on the device's external storage (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to find a solution on the internet, to try to make this listing using the kotlin language, however, I did not find anything that would help me to list all the files contained in a specific directory. If anyone can help me I will thank you. If the solution is in Java it will also help. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several researches, I found a way to carry out this functionality and I will share it here with you for future experiences

```
val storageDirectory =
        getExternalFilesDir("your_path")?.absolutePath



    val file = File(
        storageDirectory)
            .walk()
            .forEach {
                Toast.makeText(this,it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, and you didn't put any code of how your directory path look, however, try the following :

```
File[] files = new File(YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH).listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) 
                for (File file : files) 
                    Log.d("FILE", "--> "+file.getName());
```

Comment: Sorry for the clarity and objectivity of the question, but I found how to do it, I'll put it as an answer here